# Unable to deploying Spring boot with JNDI in Wildfly

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, jndi

I am trying to deploy my springboot application as a war file created with maven on Wildfly server and getting below exception which is not getting resolved after so many attempts.Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Please find below exception trace.

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"assignment.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/JdbcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/JdbcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/JdbcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/jdbc/repository/config/JdbcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist"}}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/PostgresDS
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

## JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

and also my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>ir.zabetan</groupId>
<artifactId>master</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>master</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>Alireza Zabetan Assignment</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
        <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Swagger-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>assignment</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<!--<build>-->
    <!--<pluginManagement>-->
        <!--<plugins>-->
            <!--<plugin>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<version>2.4</version>-->
                <!--<configuration>-->
                    <!--<warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>-->
                    <!--<warName>Assignment</warName>-->
                    <!--<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->
        <!--</plugins>-->
    <!--</pluginManagement>-->
    <!--<finalName>Assignment</finalName>-->
<!--</build>-->
```

Comment: Can you show your project structure?

Comment: Why do you have spring-boot-starter-undertow and commons-dbcp as dependency?

Comment: Wildfly works with undertow and also a programmer told me to use the commons-dbcp dependecy due to solving "JdbcConfiguration.class".